# C++11 support in NativeLibrary for Android

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, android-native-library

I'm trying to create a native library in C++, which I can use in Android. 
I've created a project in Visual Studio 2017: Dynamic Shared Library (Android), and added my cpp code.

Though some of the code is running C++11, and I'd really like to keep it that way.
When I compile, I get the error:

```
This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. 
This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

So I first tried going to Project->Properties->C/C++->Language->C++ Language Standard, and set the options as following:

'[image: Config]

When I compile now, I get exactly the same error. So I tried manually adding the `-std=c++11` flag under additional options, though still getting the error.

Why is the compiler not willing to compile using the ++11 standard, and what can I do to fix this? I know it's experimental, but it should at least try to compile.

Best regards

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using?

Comment: What code is producing that message and can we see it.  The settings look like it is compiling with C++14 maybe the test in the code is too specific.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved, when I changed the settings to be for All Platforms, and not just ARM.